# Is it a good idea to create multiple heads with Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I just made a commit that I want to reverse, but I want to keep the bad commit in history. So, I `hg update` to the previous (good) commit. Then I keep working.

This leaves me with a new head: the abandoned bad commit.

Is this bad practice? What's the best way to keep bad commits in history while not using them?

Comment: Yes it's a terrible idea, read more of the links in the answers below especially this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506803/difference-between-revert-and-update-in-mercurial

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the branch you don't have to have it, use hg revert.

using revert will still keep the bad commit in history, it will create a new commit that undoes the changes from the bad commit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506803/difference-between-revert-and-update-in-mercurial gives the difference between the two if you want to know that

Comment: +1, and remember you can revert the revert if you want to bring the changes back again.

Comment: Is this the preferred way to keep bad commits? I guess I'm looking for best-practices; it seems like either way would work.

Comment: yes id say it is preferred compared to branching (via update)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep track of the mistake in the history you want to use [backout](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Backout). The backout command will create a new commit that cancel the previous one. You can even document why original commit is a mistake.

Comment: There are many reasons why adding extra heads is bad, it complicates or destroys ability to safely push/pull and merge for one thing.